# Bash parse log file value and timestamp two rows underneath

Tags: bash, parsing

I have file with the following format:

```
[2019-11-03 02:23:16] DEBUG : [COST METRICS] Found 10927 cost entries to copy.
[2019-11-03 02:23:16] DEBUG : [COST METRICS] Copying relevant cost data over via query: [..sql query here...]
[2019-11-03 02:25:13] DEBUG : [REVENUE METRICS] Fetching count of groups to be updated...
--
[2019-11-03 02:45:09] DEBUG : [COST METRICS] Found 4970 cost entries to copy into new table A_294472
[2019-11-03 02:45:09] DEBUG : [COST METRICS] Copying relevant cost data over via query: [..sql query here..]
[2019-11-03 02:45:15] DEBUG : [REVENUE METRICS] Fetching count of groups to be updated
```

The above format repeats several times in the file.
What I'd like to get, is the number number of cost entries to update, the timestamp of that log line, as well as the timestamp two lines underneath (which is when the query would have finished and the script moved to the next task. So my desired output here would be:

```
Number   Start      Finish
10927    02:23:16   02:25:13
```

Perhaps even a timing column showing **00:01:57** for this scenario if possible.
I am trying to accomplish this with grep and egrep, but not really getting anywhere as I cannot reuse the value and echo it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

something like this will work, may not be robust enough for all cases since your sample input is very limited...

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
           if($i=="Found") {t=$2; sub("]","",t); v=$(i+1); n=NR; next}} 
   t && NR==n+2 {sub("]","",$2); print v,t,$2; t=""}' file

10927 02:23:16 02:25:13
```

Comment: Thank you, I added another example row

Answer (score 1):

This I think will accomplish what you are looking for using egrep and awk

```
egrep -A2 "^\[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\].*\[COST METRICS\] Found" test.txt | grep -v '\-\-' | awk '{ORS="\n"} NR==1 {print "Number  Start     Finish" }; {ORS=""} NR%3==1 {print $8"   "substr($2,0,8)} NR%3==0 {print "  "substr($2,0,8)"\n" }'
```

Where test.txt is your log file

Sample output:

```
Number  Start     Finish
10927   02:23:16  02:25:13
10927   02:25:16  02:25:16
55097   02:28:16  02:29:13
66927   02:29:16  02:30:15
77927   02:31:16  02:31:18
```